# jq: how do I update a value based on a substring match?

Tags: json, regex, url, jq, string-matching

I've got a **jq** question.  Given a file **file.json** containing:

```
[
  {
    "type": "A",
    "name": "name 1",
    "url": "http://domain.com/path/to/filenameA.zip"
  },
  {
    "type": "B",
    "name": "name 2",
    "url": "http://domain.com/otherpath/to/filenameB.zip"
  },
  {
    "type": "C",
    "name": "name 3",
    "url": "http://otherdomain.com/otherpath/to/filenameB.zip"
  }
]
```

I'm looking to create another file using **jq** with url modified only if the url's value matches some pattern.  For example, I'd want to update any url matching the pattern:

```
http://otherdomain.com.*filenameB.*
```

to some fixed string such as:

```
http://yetanotherdomain.com/new/path/to/filenameC.tar.gz
```

with the resulting json:

```
[
  {
    "type": "A",
    "name": "name 1",
    "url": "http://domain.com/path/to/filenameA.zip"
  },
  {
    "type": "B",
    "name": "name 2",
    "url": "http://domain.com/otherpath/to/filenameB.zip"
  },
  {
    "type": "C",
    "name": "name 3",
    "url": "http://yetanotherdomain.com/new/path/to/filenameB.tar.gz"
  }
]
```

I haven't gotten far even on being able to find the url, let alone update it.  This is as far as I've gotten (wrong results and doesn't help me with the update issue):

```
% cat file.json | jq -r '.[] | select(.url | index("filenameB")).url'
http://domain.com/otherpath/to/filenameB.zip
http://otherdomain.com/otherpath/to/filenameB.zip
%
```

Any ideas on how to get the path of the key that has a value matching a regex?  And after that, how to update the key with some new string value?  If there are multiple matches, all should be updated with the same new value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The good news is that there's a simple solution to the problem:

```
map( if .url | test("http://otherdomain.com.*filenameB.*")
     then .url |= sub(  "http://otherdomain.com.*filenameB.*"; 
           "http://yetanotherdomain.com/new/path/to/filenameC.tar.gz")
     else .
     end)
```

The not-so-good news is that it's not so easy to explain unless you understand the key cleverness here - the "|=" filter.  There is plenty of jq documentation about it, so I'll just point out that it is similar to the += family of operators in the C family of programming languages.

Specifically, `.url |= sub(A;B)` is like `.url = (.url|sub(A;B))`.  That is how the update is done "in-place".

Comment: Thanks for the update portion of the answer.  It works.  How would I get the path to the found element?  I might want this if I wanted to save the path so that later on in a bash script I could use that path to update that particular element.  I need really two separate operations: find the path to an element that matches a pattern, and update an element with a new value.

Comment: @SteveAmerige - I'm not exactly sure what your additional question (or questions) is (or are), but you might like to read up on `..` or perhaps ask a separate SO "question".

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.

Comment: I like both of the answers for educational purposes and I've upvoted them both. Because of the conciseness, I'm marking this as the accepted answer. By the way, sorry for the delay in getting back to this. Your effort deserved a more timely reply!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution which identifies paths to url members with **tostream** and **select** and then updates the values using **reduce** and **setpath**

```
  "http://otherdomain.com.*filenameB.*"                      as $from
| "http://yetanotherdomain.com/new/path/to/filenameC.tar.gz" as $to

| reduce (tostream | select(length == 2 and .[0][-1] == "url")) as $p (
      .
    ; setpath($p[0]; $p[1] | sub($from; $to))
  )
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much for helping out!